# How to solve $\frac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}t} = (\beta - \gamma)I$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

I need help with solving this exponential growth equation:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}t} = (\beta - \gamma)I.$$

Comment: Can you solve $dI/dt=\alpha I$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the term $(\beta - \gamma)$ is independent of $t$, then it's the same case as solving the differential equation $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}t} = aI$ where $a \in \mathbb R$ is a constant. Thus you just separate (in the case of $I \neq 0)$:

$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}t} = (\beta - \gamma)I \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{I}\mathrm{d}I = (\beta-\gamma)dt \Rightarrow \int \frac{1}{I}\mathrm{d}I = \int(\beta-\gamma)dt $$
$$\implies$$
$$\ln  I(t) = (\beta - \gamma)t + C \Leftrightarrow I(t) = C'e^{(\beta-\gamma)t}$$
where $C \in \mathbb R$ is the indefinite integration consant and $C' = e^C$. This can be calculated by some initial conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are constant with respect to t, then:

$\frac{I'}{I}=\beta -\gamma \to ln(I)=(\beta-\gamma)t+C \to I=ce^{(\beta-\gamma)t}$

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems to solve this kind of first order equations (separable equation), tthis easy-rule will  help you: you can see the differential operator as a "fraction"
$$\dfrac{dI}{dt} = (\beta-\gamma)I$$

$$\frac{1}{I}dI = (\beta-\gamma)dt$$

$$\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{I}dI = \int(\beta-\gamma)dt$$ 
$$\ln(I) = (\beta-\gamma)t+C$$
$$I = K\cdot e^{(\beta-\gamma)t}$$

Comment: It is important to note that $I \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $β$ and $\gamma$ depend on time, with the same method as Rebellos, you would find
$$
\ln I(t) = \ln I(0) + \int_0^t \beta(s)-\gamma(s)\,\mathrm{d}s,
$$
so that at the end you get
$$
I(t) = I(0)\, e^{\int_0^t \beta(s)-\gamma(s)\,\mathrm{d}s}.
$$